# Sql - Calculate amount for last 7 days

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to write sql where I can return amount for each day using groupBy per DATE.

My fields are amount and transaction_date and my sql is:

```
select id,    
Amount as amount,    
transactionDate as transaction_date      
from transaction    
WHERE transactionDate IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 transactionDate from transaction
order by transactionDate)
```

So, my sql syntax is wrong and I can't figure out what to do next.

Comment: What error are you getting?  What database are you using (please tag appropriately)?  One small comment is that you would seem to want `order by transactionDate desc` for the logic you are asking for.

Comment: I am using mysql for symfony app development on local. Everything seems to be working fine but when I try to add IN (SELECT DISTINCT TOP 7 transactionDate  it reports an error in syntax,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below way

```
select date(transactionDate) as transaction_date  
sum(Amount) as amount           
from transaction    
WHERE date(transactionDate)>=  DATE_ADD(current_date(),INTERVAL -7 DAY)
group by date(transactionDate)
```

BTW `Top` is sql server key word not for mysql

Answer (score 0):

use aggregation and group by

```
select transactionDate     
sum(Amount) as amount,    
from transaction  
where transactionDate>=cast(now()-INTERVAL -7 DAY as date) and transactionDate<cast(now() as date)
group by transactionDate
```

Answer (score -1):

Thank you all, you give my a path that I can go and finish. I found the solution. Thanks a lot.

```
 SELECT
 DATE(transaction_date) AS TransactionDate, SUM(amount) AS Amount
 FROM transaction
 WHERE type = 'spend'
 AND transaction_date>=  DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -7 DAY)
 GROUP BY TransactionDate
```